# NetServiceBrowser gives a different NetService when Removed

Tags: ios, nsnetservicebrowser

I was hoping to do something like this:

In `netServiceBrowser:didFindService:moreComing:`

```
[self.foundServices addObject:aNetService];
```

And in `netServiceBrowser:didRemoveService:moreComing:`

```
[self.foundServices removeObject:aNetService];
```

However, the services returned aren't retained by the NetServiceBrowser, and so the service given in `didRemoveService` isn't the same object as those in the array.  How do I compare the services to ensure that the one I remove is the correct one?

Comment: No idea why somebody downvoted this, it's a completely reasonable question. Would upvote again if I could!

Comment: Probably because the question makes incorrect assertions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're over-thinking this, and creating a problem in your head that doesn't exist. Use `removeObject:` on the object passed into `didRemoveService:`. `removeObject:` removes based on the object's response to `isEqual:`, not the address or identity of the object. So this will just work.

The answer really is as simple as:

```
[self.foundServices removeObject:aNetService];
```

Apple's description of `removeObject:` explains this:

> This method uses `indexOfObject:` to locate matches and then removes them by using `removeObjectAtIndex:`. Thus, matches are determined on the basis of an object’s response to the `isEqual:` message.

(For completeness, Apple **does** offer a function that removes an object by address. That's `removeObjectIdenticalTo:`. That's not the behaviour you want here, however. Just use `removeObject:`.)

References:

- [NSMutableArray Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000138-BABDAJBB)
- [Apple Sample Code: BrowserViewController.m](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/BonjourWeb/Listings/BonjourSupport_BrowserViewController_m.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007415-BonjourSupport_BrowserViewController_m-DontLinkElementID_6)

Comment: This question was asked nearly 2 years ago, and I don't have access to the original code.  The problem described above DID happen, I'm guessing it was due to perhaps pre-release code, or something funky happening in code.  My answer did work in the end, but I'm assuming that my specific problem doesn't occur anymore.

Comment: This answer was also almost two years ago, and I'd been developing for iOS since 2010. Including, yes, NSNetService work. I don't doubt what you thought you saw, but you were incorrect in one of your assumptions. This has always worked. In fact, you can see I posted this answer **on the same day** as you posted yours.

Comment: And to be completely clear: I completely sympathize, because at the time I thought `removeObject:` wouldn't do what I wanted. Then I tested it and found it did *exactly* what I needed it to do.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer, I ended up having to use this, but I can't reproduce the problem anymore.  Use the selected answer.

```
- (void)netServiceBrowser:(NSNetServiceBrowser *)aNetServiceBrowser didFindService:(NSNetService *)aNetService moreComing:(BOOL)moreComing {
    [self.foundServices addObject:aNetService];
}


- (void)netServiceBrowser:(NSNetServiceBrowser *)aNetServiceBrowser didRemoveService:(NSNetService *)aNetService moreComing:(BOOL)moreComing {
    NSNetService *found = nil;

    for(NSNetService *ns in self.foundServices) {
        if([ns isEqualTo:aNetService]) {
            found = ns;
        }
    }

    if(found) {
        [self.foundServices removeObject:found];
    }
}
```

Comment: This is unnecessary; you're just rebuilding a slightly incorrect version of `removeObject:`.